# Extract month name from raw string?

Tags: python, monthcalendar

Extract month name from raw string

```
'January 2045 Robots'
'2065 March Mars Colony'
'2089 December Alien'
```

I want to extract month name from raw string, I took an approch to extract it by creating master tuple

```
s = 'January 2045 Robots'
months_master = ('january','feb','march','april','may','june','july','august','september','october','november','december')
month = [i for i in months_master if i in s.casefold()]
print(month[0])
'january'
```

Is there any elegent or any pythonic way to achieve this

Note: For now requirement input string only contains single month ( not multiple like `s = 'May to December Bio'` )

Comment: slight remark, you might wich to use .lower() so that case doesn't bother you. e.g.: `month = [i for i in months_master if i in s.casefold().lower()]`

Comment: What about [`'May to December'`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/May_to_December)?

Comment: @PeterWood Not required for now

Comment: Your method is pretty good.Why don't you want to use it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could import the month names from the built-in [`calendar`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/calendar.html#calendar.month_name) module and also use a *generator* instead of a list comprehension for better efficiency:

```
>>> from calendar import month_name
>>> s = 'January 2045 Robots'
>>> months = {m.lower() for m in month_name[1:]}  # create a set of month names
>>> next((word for word in s.split() if word.lower() in months), None)
'January'
```

Alternatively, you could use a [regular expression](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html):

```
>>> from calendar import month_name
>>> import re
>>> pattern = '|'.join(month_name[1:])
>>> re.search(pattern, s, re.IGNORECASE).group(0)
'January'
```

Answer (score 1):

The `calendar` module provides a generator for localised month names called `month_name`. This list does include an empty string, however, so you need to catch that, and the months appear in title case ("January" etc), so you need to catch for that too. We do this by using `if x and x in s.title()` - when `x` is the empty string, this evaluates to `False`.

```
from calendar import month_name
s = 'January 2045 Robots'
month = [x for x in month_name if x and x in s.title()]
```

Answer (score 0):

Using word split or word tokenize and see if the word is in the month list

```
text = 'January 2045 Robots'
month_master = ('january','feb','march','april','may','june','july','august','september','october','november','december')
month_found = [word for word in text.split() if word.lower() in month_master]

# output ['January']
```

Answer (score 0):

You can store your months in a `set` instead of a tuple and check if a word is in this set. This will reduce time complexity from O(N*M), where N is the length of a string and M is the length of the `months_master` tuple to just O(N).
Something like that:

```
    months_master = set("january", "february", ...)
    month = [word for word in s.casefold().split() if word in months_master]
```

Comment: How expensive is `split`? Also this would match multiple months, or keep checking even after finding one.

Comment: It's O(N) as well, but it's executed only once, so overall complexity is `O(N) + O(N) * O(1)`; ergo, `O(N)`. And potential extra results don't bother OP.